# Why rare events carry much information?

Tags: binomial-distribution, rare-events

Consider a non-symmetric coin experiment where $p$ is the probability to get heads. I flip the coin $n$ times and try to estimate the value of $p$. The amount of heads has the binomial distribution so the Fisher information for the distribution parameter $p$ is
$$I_p = \frac{n}{p(1-p)}$$
and the variance for an effective estimator is
$$D_p = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}.$$
When $p$ is very small one got a very high information and low variance so I need much smaller sample size to get the same accuracy as for the case $p=1/2$.

What is the intuition behind that? Why am I almost certain about the value of $p$ after few throws if it is small?

Comment: you are not, it's the other way round. I don't really understand your reasoning, but I think this is partly to do with variance Vs fractional variance. It might be true, that if p is small, your confidence/credible intervals will be "smaller" in absolute terms but not relative. If you know that $p=0.5 \pm 0.05$, to me, that's more informative than if you know $p=0.05  \pm 0.04$, as in the former case, you're saying p is between 0.45-0.55, and in the latter case, you're saying it's between 0.01 and 0.09. I would argue that in the former case, you have more certainty

Comment: related question that I asked: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80899/intuitive-reason-why-the-fisher-information-of-binomial-is-inversely-proportiona